# Configuring Torrent/Download Managers to use the Lowest Possible Speed if other Resources aren't using Internet

Tags: download, bittorrent, internet-speed

How can i configure my **DM**s to lower its downloading speed and be flexible if other software is using internet?

I always doubted something in these download managers like for example:

**Internt Download Manager**'s **Max. Connection Number**, It is set on 8 by default, And i thought that if i lowered it to **1** it would consume less Internet, But then i fear it would make Files hard to be ***Resumed***.

Same goes to

**MEGA**'s **Number of TCP connections per transfer** it is set to 4(Download) and 3(Upload)

And also

**QBittorrent**'s **Connection Limits** which is set on **500 for Global** and **100 per torrent**

Does lowering the **connections** make the speed high as it is If nothing is consuming the Internet but low if not?

**Torrent**s usually lowers its speed if something else is downloading, So i thought that it is possible because of that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This question is about Quality of Service (QoS). I don't know about qBittorrent (maybe its feature called `bandwidth scheduler` is able to do this), but such control should be looked for in some system level setting.

Since you didn't specify which OS you are using, I will provide Windows example. All supported editions, that have Group Policy Editor (I think that means servers and PRO/ULT editions), are able to do this. [This article at MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc771283(v=ws.11).aspx) tells us how, and this is the screen showing it on my computer. I will not delve in detail how to do this, because I don't know. Never used it and *probably* never will.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

While it is possible to give bandwidth priority to certain devices over one another in your LAN, I do not believe that, without third party software, it is possible to give priority to certain applications automatically depending on certain conditions. You could manually tweak how much data is allowed to be downloaded/uploaded per second in your torrent client/download manager whenever you needed more bandwidth for other sources.